# Imperatively get the path for a databound attribute/property in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

If I've got some sort of declared element that I've bound data to, say this:
    `<paper-button data-mine$="[[datastore.somekey]]">`

Is there a way to access the actual 'path' ('datastore.somekey') that is used in the data-binding? Not the value, but the path that the databinding used to get to that value.

I have a few hundred elements that I would like to bind an attribute to an object.key for the attribute value. When an event is triggered though, I would like to know the path to that value. I know I could specify it as another attribute like: `<paper-button data-mine$="[[datastore.somekey]] data-path$="[[datastore.somekey]]">` But with hundreds of elements, this adds alot of repetitive text.